# Google oauth2 redirecting requests from subdomain to main domain

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-oauth

I have a domain, https://faduense.com,  where I have succesfully implemented login with google Oauth2 using passport. The app is a Mern App, which handles login via the API done in Node.

Now, since the app is a bit heavy, I want to move my app to the subdomain, https://app.faduense.com, which I already did, its working in its own server.

The issue comes to the following: I've changed all my settings inside my back and front end, but when I press login with google it still sends my requests to the main domain: https://faduense.com

I even tried creating a different app through the google console, and putting a new client and secret ID, but it still routes it via the main domain.

These are my settings:
Passport settings.

[image: Passport settings]

My user API routes which go to https://app.faduense.com/api/users/

[image]

And my popup on the front end which looks the following.[image]

Finally my credentials which look like this: 
[image]

I am at loss of words.
What I have done,

I tried changing my redirect uri in the main domain app created at google console, which gave the redirect_uri_mismatch error

I tried adding my subdomain redirect uri to the main domain app created at google console, that did nothing.

I tried to manipulate the parameters sent via the browser adress bar, to no avail.

If you go to https://app.faduense.com/login and click on login via google, the request url sends the following url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ffaduense.com%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fusuario&scope=profile%20email&client_id=54622388608-9ml71v7gsj9f2avru52hpgmh0auudbur.apps.googleusercontent.com

You can see the redirect_uri clearly is missing the subdomain.
I do not have much experience, I have searched a lot, but I see my only way out here is to ask someone with more experience.
Any clues?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.
I do not know how exactly I did it, but this is what I did:

1. First, I deleted the credentials in the google api console.
2. Then I created new credentials directly with my subdomain url.
3. I changed my secret and client id on passport JS; as well as changing my url on the frontend.
4. Tested in dev enviroment, was getting a redirect_uri error, but thats ok, since I was using localhost, and my credentials were set with my final url.
5. Used putty to get into my EC2 instance, I did sudo systemctl stop nginx, to stop the server.
6. I pulled my updated repo from github with the new secret, and client ID from the new credentials.
7. Rebooted the instance on AWS panel.
8. Finally, I started nginx again, sudo systemctl start nginx.
9. Test it live, and its working.